# Why Doesn't Mathematica Simplify Combinations of Quotients? (Integer Division)

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I stumbled across this as part of a more complicated formula but it can be shown very simply:

```
In[1]:= f[x_] := Quotient[Quotient[x, 5], 7]; FullSimplify[f[x]]

Out[1]= Quotient[Quotient[x, 5], 7]

In[2]:= FullSimplify[f[x], Element[x, Integers] && x >= -1000 && x <= 1000]

Out[2]= Quotient[Quotient[x, 5], 7]

In[3]:= f[x] == Quotient[x, 35] /. x -> Range[-1000, 1000]

Out[3]= True
```

Why doesn't Mathematica make the simplification shown to be true in step 3?

EDIT 2: The following works for me, using the identity pointed out by RiemannZeta:

```
In[1]:= f[x_] := Quotient[Quotient[x, 5], 7]
        FullSimplify[f[x]]
        FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[f[x]]]

Out[2]= Quotient[Quotient[x, 5], 7]

Out[3]= Floor[1/7 Floor[x/5]]

In[4]:= Unprotect[Floor];
        Floor[Floor[x_ Rational[1, m_]] Rational[1, n_]] := 
         Floor[x/(n m)] /; Element[{m, n}, Integers] && m > 0 && n > 0
        FunctionExpand[f[x]]
        FunctionExpand[f[x] == Quotient[x, 35]]

Out[6]= Floor[x/35]

Out[7]= True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `TransformationFunctions`:

```
f[x_] := Quotient[Quotient[x, 5], 7];
quotsimp[Quotient[Quotient[x_, n_], m_]] /; Refine[Element[x, Integers]] := Quotient[x, n m]

Assuming[Element[x, Integers],
  FullSimplify[f[x], TransformationFunctions -> {quotsimp, Automatic}]
]

(* Quotient[x, 35] *)
```

Comment: Interesting! I notice you include the assumption that x is an integer as part of this; is the simplification not valid if x is real or complex?  I wonder if that's why Mathematica doesn't do it...

Comment: Brief experimentation seems to show that if x is real or complex it is still valid, but if either of the divisors is real then it isn't.

Comment: I'm not sure, I added that restriction because I saw you had the line `FullSimplify[f[x], Element[x, Integers] && x >= -1000 && x <= 1000]`.

Comment: The identity appears to hold for all `x`. First note Quotient[x, n] == Floor[x/n]. Next, see the second identity in the quotients section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients. (in fact the identity there is more general!)

Comment: Very interesting!  To see if I could get Mathematica to "understand" that identity (in the simple case where m==0), `Floor[Floor[x/y]/z] /. Floor[Floor[a_/b_]/c_] -> Floor[a/(b c)]` works, but when you make y or z a literal value, e.g. `Floor[Floor[x/y]/7]` the pattern doesn't match.  It seems Mathematica is choosing to represent division by an integer as multiplication by its inverse; as this is no longer obviously an integer, and the identity doesn't hold if n is non-integer, I wonder if this is why the simplification isn't made?  Thanks for the clue!

Comment: Look at `FullForm[Floor[Floor[x/y]/7]]` to see why your replacement rule isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You can make this happen without much trouble by defining your own version of Quotient:

```
q[x_, n_] := Quotient[x, n];
q[q[x_, n_], m_] := q[x, n m];
```

Here I've used `q` for shorthand. It is the same as quotient, but it also "knows" a rule for simplifying double Quotients. Hence

```
q[q[x,5],7]
```

gives the desired `Quotient[x, 35]`.

Comment: Nice! I've added this workaround to the question.  Wondering if applying this to the built-in Quotient function would break anything?

Comment: There's always lots of ways to break things. It would make me nervous redefining the built-in function. At least with your own definition, you know right where the problem is.